# ¿Hay manera de detectar si se está navegando en modo incógnito?

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy haciendo una página que utiliza las notificaciones de escritorio del navegador. Esto solo funciona correctamente si NO se está en modo incógnito, ¿cómo hacen ciertas páginas para detectar que estás en modo incognito?, por ejemplo `MEGA` no te deja descargar nada en modo incógnito, emite una alerta diciendo

> File transfers do not work with Chrome Incognito. (Security Error in
>   RequestFileSystem)

al igual que si entras a la tienda de Chrome en modo incógnito te aparece un mensaje diciendo

> Algunas de las funciones de Chrome Web Store no están disponibles en
>   el modo incógnito.

¿Cómo puedo hacer esto mismo? y que **funcione para cualquier navegador**.

Comment: Hay un pregunta muy similar en StackOverflow: [Can you determine if Chrome is in incognito mode via a script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2909367)

Comment: No entiendo lo del `iframe` :/

Comment: Ten por seguro que si estuviera capacitado para escribir una respuesta, lo habría hecho :-( por eso lo dejé como comentario, a ver si alguien se anima a colocarlo detallado y en español.

Comment: Gracias igual, si ví el post pero no sé, no comprendo la opción, según dice todo, lo que hace es ver el color de un link, para saber si está o no en incognito, pero para eso usan el iframe y de eso si no sé jaja

Comment: ¿Necesitas que sea en JS? Parece que sería más fácil hacerlo desde el servidor

Comment: Por velocidad quisiera desde JS, pero si tienes otra forma de hacerlo no tengo problema en verla

Comment: La cosa es que los navegadores mandan una cabecera http diferente en modo incógnito. Entonces podrías detectar el modo incógnito en el lado del servidor

Comment: Eso si no lo sé hacer, primera vez que lo escucho

Answer (score 3):

> Ésta es una traducción (adaptada) de la [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909367/can-you-determine-if-chrome-is-in-incognito-mode-via-a-script) con más votos en una pregunta similar del sitio en inglés ([enlazada por Trauma en los comentarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/66253/hay-manera-de-detectar-si-se-est%C3%A1-navegando-en-modo-inc%C3%B3gnito#comment121052_66253))

Sí hay manera: La API FileSystem esta deshabilitad en modo incógnito. Puedes verlo en este [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w49x9f1a/) cuando estás y no estás en modo incógnito.

Entonces podrías crear un pequeño snippet que haga una comprobación: si funciona, no estás en modo incógnito; si falla, estás en modo incógnito. Código de ejemplo:

```
var fs = window.RequestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
if (!fs) {
  console.log("¿Falló la prueba?");
} else {
  fs(window.TEMPORARY,
     100,
     console.log.bind(console, "No estás en modo incógnito"),
     console.log.bind(console, "Estás en modo incógnito"));
}
```

Comment: Esto funciona en Chrome, pero si lo intentas en Mozillas (como lo hice) la validación no funciona... o como podría ser?, porque allí aparece el error de `Fallo la prueba`

Answer (score 0):

Esta me funciono a mi:

```js
function detectPrivateMode(cb) {
    var db,
    on = cb.bind(null, true),
    off = cb.bind(null, false)

    function tryls() {
        try {
            localStorage.length ? off() : (localStorage.x = 1, localStorage.removeItem("x"), off());
        } catch (e) {
            // Safari only enables cookie in private mode
            // if cookie is disabled then all client side storage is disabled
            // if all client side storage is disabled, then there is no point
            // in using private mode
            navigator.cookieEnabled ? on() : off();
        }
    }

    // Blink (chrome & opera)
    window.webkitRequestFileSystem ? webkitRequestFileSystem(0, 0, off, on)
    // FF
    : "MozAppearance" in document.documentElement.style ? (db = indexedDB.open("test"), db.onerror = on, db.onsuccess = off)
    // Safari
    : /constructor/i.test(window.HTMLElement) || window.safari ? tryls()
    // IE10+ & edge
    : !window.indexedDB && (window.PointerEvent || window.MSPointerEvent) ? on()
    // Rest
    : off()
}

detectPrivateMode(function (isPrivateMode) {
    alert('is private mode: ' + isPrivateMode)
})
```