# ¿Hay forma de detectar si se está navegando en modo incógnito?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5, drupal7

Se que esta pregunta se ha hecho varias veces y que esta [repetida aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/66253/hay-manera-de-detectar-si-se-est%C3%A1-navegando-en-modo-inc%C3%B3gnito), pero ninguna solución de aquella fecha sirve en la actualidad.

¿Hay manera de detectar si se está navegando en modo incógnito?

Comment: El Fiddle en esa página funciona perfecto...

Comment: *ninguna solución de aquella fecha sirve en la actualidad.* ¿Podrías al menos indicar el porqué no sirve en la actualidad? ¿Recibes errores? ¿Cuáles? Las API que allí se mencionan siguen en uso en la actualidad.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Hay manera de detectar si se está navegando en modo incógnito?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/66253/hay-manera-de-detectar-si-se-est%c3%a1-navegando-en-modo-inc%c3%b3gnito)

Comment: ¿[Esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909367/can-you-determine-if-chrome-is-in-incognito-mode-via-a-script) Responde tu duda?

Comment: Este en modo incognito o no, siempre me dice que no lo estoy.

Comment: Te añado el link de que SI funciona en Chrome... https://i.gyazo.com/d63c8647c121eecb0f1e51219cc7e4ee.png

Comment: ¿Me compartes ese código para probar?

Comment: Es el fiddle de la página...

Comment: @JoseDarioCorrea el codigo funciona perfecto

Comment: ¿Porque a mí siempre me dice que no estoy en modo incognito aun cuando lo estoy? ¿En qué varía? ¿Hay que hacer o ajustar algo adicional?

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/66253/hay-manera-de-detectar-si-se-est%C3%A1-navegando-en-modo-inc%C3%B3gnito

Comment: Por favor, muestra ambos testeos en chrome.. a ver tus resultados.